# MS Access Joining Three tables on same field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following tables

```
t1:     t2:        t3:
id      id  f1     id  f2
1       1   a      3   a
2       2   b      4   b
3       3   c      5   c
4
5
```

and I am trying to get the following result

```
t4:
id    f1    f2
1     a
2     b
3     c     a
4           b
5           c
```

I am using the following query

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.f1, t3.f2 
FROM (t1 
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id) AS a 
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t1.id = t3.id
```

It works but the query takes a while to run. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks

Comment: If you know VBA you could create a temp table and insert data with an inner join to t2 and t3.  If you don't know VBA it's probably not worth the effort unless the query is taking 20+ minutes and it's run fairly often.

Answer (score 0):

To offer an alternative which doesn't involve additional tables: you could perhaps try structuring the SQL to perform a nested `SELECT` query such that only tables are joined for each `SELECT` query, but I doubt that this would offer a drastic improvement over what you have:

```
SELECT tmp.id, tmp.f1, t3.f2
FROM 
    (SELECT t1.id, t2.f1 FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id) AS tmp
    LEFT JOIN t3 ON tmp.id = t3.id
```